# Global search operators for approximate MAP inference?

Tags: bayesian, inference, expectation-maximization

In complicated Bayesian models, like for instance a hierarchical nonparameteric one, often times it's intractable to do Gibbs or other MCMC sampling methods to convergence. Rather, people tend to do variational inference and use expectation maximization to find the approximate MAP parameters.

Is there a reason people use a local search algorithm like EM rather than a global search algorithm like CMA-ES? It seems like the latter would require much less effort since you don't need to derive the E and M steps.

Answer (score 0):

Gibbs and MCMC methods are sampling methods. EM methods are optimisation methods. Two very different things. The first ones sample from the posterior distribution, the other one finds a maximum/minimum.

EM algorithms are used whenever you can conduct the E and M steps relatively easy. Otherwise, you usually go for some other sort of optimisation method such as the one you mention.

Comment: My point is that often times you want to do MCMC to approximate the entire posterior (e.g., to get the predictive) but it's intractable, so people go with just trying to find the MAP parameters, which is usually formatted as an optimization problem. However, if you look at most papers in NIPS or other related venues, usually the authors choose to do a variational approximation and then apply EM, rather than treating the full posterior as an optimization problem that requires a global search operator. I'm wondering if there is a reason or if it's just a bias in the machine learning community.